# Get the status message string

Tags: 8, status-messages

I tried to get the string messages and create a condition based on the string, but I don't know how to pull the string value.

This is an example of message.

> [image]

Comment: Can you provide more details, where you have written this kint(). Just try to access the variable by $args['error']->string->__toString().

Comment: @RazeemAhmad `string` is a protected property. It  cannot be accessed outside the class or the class hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno for pointing that! I wonder how can we access those variables??

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pull the string, you can use the markup object in a string comparision directly:

```
$markup = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create('Test');

if ($markup == 'Test') {
  // the markup string is "Test"
}
```

When you want to use triple equals then you have to type cast the object to a string first:

```
if ((string) $markup === 'Test') {
  // the markup string is "Test"
}
```

Comment: Im sorry but where did you get the 'Test'? Is the mark up is the method to get the the message value?

Comment: `$markup` is an example, in your case this is `$xyz['error'][0]` where xyz is the variable name you put in kint().